# Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Decimal to Integer

Tags: apex

```
itemlst.Quantity = templook[i].Quantity__c;
```

Here Quantity is of integer type and Quantity_*c is of decimal type.How can I convert Quantity*_c into Integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_integer.htm

```
itemlst.Quantity = integer.valueOf(templook[i].Quantity__c);
```

Integer.valueOf will work.

Edit:

```
 Decimal myDecimal = 4.12;
 Integer a=myDecimal.intValue();
  System.debug('*****'+a);
```

I used Decimal.intValue() and it works as shown.

Comment: When should I use decimalvalue.intvalue();

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm     Thats an instance method and you will need an decimal instance and then get the value

Comment: I updated my answer .You may like to refer that too.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Decimal.intValue, means you need extra check or you'll get null pointer exception ;) `Decimal d = null;
System.debug(Integer.valueOf(d));` works and outputs null